# How do you make internals visible to nCrunch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ncrunch

MyProject has an internal class and method as such.

```
namespace MyProject
{    
    internal class InboundMailAlertParser
    {
        internal InboundMailAlert ParseMessageBody(string body)
        { 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using InternalsVisibleTo in my MyProject AssemblyInfo.cs to expose internal classes/methods to a unit test assembly.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Tests")]
```

My Test looks like this

```
namespace MyProject.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class InboundMailAlertParserTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ParsesBody()
        {           
            InboundMailAlertParser parser = new InboundMailAlertParser();
            parser.ParseMessageBody(messageBody.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

My test passes fine when run in Visual Studio, but nCrunch is failing to build the unit test project due to not being able to see the internal InboundMailAlertParser of the MyProject assembly under test.  Is there another nCrunch assembly I have to indicate should have internal visiblity to allow nCrunch to be able to build the test assembly?

Comment: That's very odd - it should be absolutely fine. I don't have any problems with this in Noda Time (using nCrunch). Have you tried a clean rebuild?

Comment: Getting this in the NCrunch tests window with a clean build and restart:  InboundMailAlertParserTests.cs (26)#0: The type or namespace name 'InboundMailAlertParser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hmm. If it builds under VS it should be fine in NCrunch. Are your assemblies signed?

Comment: Not even a little bit.  =\  I've had other issues with things not building and requiring me to set up specific dependencies such as MS Fakes settings files and whatnot.

Comment: When this happened to me, I had just added InternalsVisibleTo to the csproj file.  NCrunch threw that error until I restarted VS, cleaned, and rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had ignored a component (project) in the nCrunch config.  Once I enabled that, the project could build correctly and I got my lovely green dots.